# Print from Windows Mobile to Bluetooth Printer

Tags: c#, windows-mobile, motorola, zebra-printers

I want to print a receipt containing text and barcode from MC75 [Windows mobile 6] and using a bluetooth printer (Zebra or any other).

I am very new to windows mobile and I don't know where to start and how to connect with bluetooth devices.

Please can someone provide me with some link or code to start with a print "hello world" via  a bluetooth printer in c#.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Zebra provides an SDK for Windows mobile](http://www.zebra.com/id/zebra/na/en/index/products/software/SDK/windows_downloads.html) which has many examples, short sample applications, and even a demo utility. You just simply call the APIs provided and the SDK will make the proper connection to the printer via Bluetooth (or TCP) for you.

Comment: Thank You For Your Kind Response.Finally am on that.ANd iam confused...how to dynamically find zebra printer in a bluetooth range and show it to user to select from the available list and print...? can i pass text file directlt to zebra printer...or hardcode like 'T 2 0 10 52 PRINT HELLO' etc...coz i hav many data in dataset and print in to a firmat...how can i do it ? did u ever used with this ? ....nothing shown in example demo...

Comment: Have you looked at the documentation? Look at the BluetoothDiscoverer class. It has code on how to find printers. On the main page of the CHM file it has quick links for how to send formats and print to a printer

Comment: Hi , I had test print.and when i create a dynamic print .its not print anything...deveie foud BT printer and pass the string like below...

Answer (score 1):

You could take a screen shot of the information on your device (example [>> HERE <<](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7817689)), then send the file via Bluetooth.

The only other idea I could think of would be to write enough data in a text file to completely describe all of the controls displayed on the device (control type, location, size, color, any text, barcode font) then send that text file to a Windows program on the paired PC to take that information and recreate your form

...then Print from Windows.